# WPF application is using a lot of GPU power

Tags: c#, wpf, gpu

I am developing a WPF App. I have added few controls around 50+ including labels buttons grid panels etc.

But on some Views the GPU power spikes to around 40-50% in the Task Manager.

What could be the issue?

I read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-taking-advantage-of-hardware)

But found no conclusion on what control could be causing this.

Comment: You didn't share any code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't think I can put all my GUI code here on this app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue which was causing it. It was the [DropShaddowEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect?view=netframework-4.8).

When I removed the DropShaddowEffect from the Grids and Borders my GPU went down to 5-6% from 40-50%. I call that a success

I also want to reference this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836549/wpf-performance-wrong-dirty-rect-calculation) from stackoverflow as the search parameters differ when searching for this kind of problem

Comment: May I know your GPU model?

Comment: @MitraM Intel HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Thanks , So my guess was right, your GPU is not strong.

Comment: I did try this on an NVidia Graphics card of my client and it produced the same result getting 40-50%